# How to get user by email id and update it in angularfire?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

Angularfire is new for me.

I have following 'users' database in firebase

```
{
  "users" : {
    "OXdf2BB0ZSO9eGAWGaeeHMAIz7k2" : {
      "displayName" : "nirmal",
      "email" : "nirmal@gmail.com",
      "username" : "nirmal"
    },
    "kuuVEQHTrZgFyv9WZmfYhNJnUSf1" : {
      "displayName" : "Mehul",
      "email" : "mehul@gmail.com",
      "username" : "malimehul"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to get user by email id and update it or add new property in user.

like:

```
var userQuery = firebase.database().ref().child("users").orderByChild('email').equalTo('nirmal@gmail.com');

userQuery.on("child_added", function (snap) {
   console.log('snap', snap.val());
   //want to updating the user is received?, want to add phone property in received user
})
```

So, want to add phone property in user(nirmal@gmail.com):
 after update user(nirmal@gmail.com) user object should look like as following

```
"OXdf2BB0ZSO9eGAWGaeeHMAIz7k2" : {
  "displayName" : "nirmal",
  "email" : "nirmal@gmail.com",
  "username" : "nirmal",
  "phone":"xxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

It is possible in angularfire?

So, How to get user by email id and update it in angularfire?

Comment: Did you write any code yet? Because as it stands I find it hard to understand what you're trying to do. By sharing the code where you are stuck, we'll be able to see better what you're trying and where you are stuck.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen: Thanks for reply.  I have update my question. Please check it... you can get it?

Answer (score 1):

To update the user:

```
var usersRef = firebase.database().ref().child("users")l
var userQuery = usersRef.orderByChild('email').equalTo('nirmal@gmail.com');

userQuery.on("child_added", function (snapshot) {
   snapshot.ref.update({ phone: "+15554084242" })
})
```

So in the new line, we're using [`ref`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#ref) to get the reference for the snapshot and then use [`update()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#update) to add/update a single property.